# mnlogit summary return a array with a lot of "nan"

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I want to study the influence of certain variables on electricity consumption. To do this, I have independent variables (X) which are categorical (gender, age, marital status) and ordinal (number of occupants). My dependent variable (y) has 4 categories which are the different electricity consumption bands. It turns out that after running the code, I obtained the output results you see below. The problem I'm having is understanding the 'nan' that appear everywhere and skew my results. How can I solve this problem?

```
# Import librairies
import pandas as pd 
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

# Loading dataset
data = pd.read_excel("donnees_socio.xlsx")
data['conso_elect_codes'] = data['conso_elect'].astype('category').cat.codes

# model classification formula 
formula = "conso_elect_codes ~ sexe + age + statut + nbre_occ"


# fit the multinomial model
model = smf.mnlogit(formula, data = data)
result = model.fit()

# Display results 
print(result.summary())
```

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: nan
         Iterations 27
                          MNLogit Regression Results                          
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:      conso_elect_codes   No. Observations:                  749
Model:                        MNLogit   Df Residuals:                      719
Method:                           MLE   Df Model:                           27
Date:                Tue, 24 Oct 2023   Pseudo R-squ.:                     nan
Time:                        11:56:11   Log-Likelihood:                    nan
converged:                       True   LL-Null:                       -562.99
Covariance Type:            nonrobust   LLR p-value:                       nan
==========================================================================================
   conso_elect_codes=1       coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept                     nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
sexe[T.Homme]                 nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
age[T.35 - 49 ans ]           nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
age[T.50 - 64 ans ]           nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
age[T.65 et plus]             nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
age[T.Moins de 25 ans]        nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
statut[T.Divorcé(e)]          nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
statut[T.Marié(e)]            nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
statut[T.Veuf(ve)]            nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
nbre_occ                      nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   conso_elect_codes=2       coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept                     nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
sexe[T.Homme]                 nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
age[T.35 - 49 ans ]           nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
age[T.50 - 64 ans ]           nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
age[T.65 et plus]             nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
age[T.Moins de 25 ans]        nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
statut[T.Divorcé(e)]          nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
statut[T.Marié(e)]            nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
statut[T.Veuf(ve)]            nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
nbre_occ                      nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   conso_elect_codes=3       coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept                     nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
sexe[T.Homme]                 nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
age[T.35 - 49 ans ]           nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
age[T.50 - 64 ans ]           nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
age[T.65 et plus]             nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
age[T.Moins de 25 ans]        nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
statut[T.Divorcé(e)]          nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
statut[T.Marié(e)]            nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
statut[T.Veuf(ve)]            nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
nbre_occ                      nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
==========================================================================================
```

Comment: try a different optimizer, e.g. `model.fit(method="bfgs", maxiter=1000)` or "nm". My guess would be that the optimizer did not converge and `converged` is true in summary is incorrect.

Comment: also how many observations are in each y category level? There could be numerical problems if the reference category has relatively few observations.

Comment: @Josef, trying to follow your suggestion doesn't work. Here's what's displayed.

`Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.612445
         Iterations: 175
         Function evaluations: 177
         `Gradient evaluations: 177`

and this one also :
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[13], line 18
     15 result = model.fit(method="bfgs", maxiter=1000)
     17 # Afficher les résultats 
---> 18 print(result.summary())

ValueError: need covariance of parameters for computing (unnormalized) covariances

Comment: about second question , I'll say, there are 749 observations 

Moins de 110 kWh     437
110 - 400 kWh        300
401 - 800 kWh         11
800 - 2000 kWh         1
Name: conso_elect, dtype: int64
======
Homme    434
Femme    315
Name: sexe, dtype: int64

25 - 34 ans        307
35 - 49 ans        243
50 - 64 ans        120
Moins de 25 ans     62
65 et plus          17
Name: age, dtype: int64

Marié(e)        460
Célibataire     251
Veuf(ve)         25
Divorcé(e)       13
Name: statut, dtype: int64

7    145
5    136
4    114
6     98
3     95
1     94
2     67

Comment: `Current function value: 0.612445` means loglike is not nan and parameters should be ok, or most of them. `ValueError: need covariance` means Hessian is not invertible. My guess is that you don't have `Divorce` in every y-level. Try dropping one of the regressors like `statut` and check whether you get the full results.

Comment: @Josef, I've deleted some regressors and made combinations of regressors, for some I have values and for others I still have "nan".

Comment: The combinations where I have 'nan', here's what I have: 
`Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: nan
         Iterations 33
                          MNLogit Regression Results                          

Dep. Variable:   conso_elect_codes   No. Observations:         749
Model:          MNLogit   Df Residuals:   728
Method:        MLE   Df Model:  18
Date:    Wed, 25 Oct 2023   Pseudo R-squ.:      nan
Time:    09:04:38   Log-Likelihood:     nan
converged:    True   LL-Null:      -562.99
Covariance Type:   nonrobust   LLR p-value:     nan

Comment: In the previous case, I used 3 regressors instead of 4 as planned

Comment: see last sentence in https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/ on empty cells and maybe https://doi.org/10.1177/2053168018769 who use crosstabs to find empty cells. (I'm not familiar with this for multinomial logit and statsmodels does not have penalized MNLogit)